# Glob string comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I have a glob string, and a file path, is it possible to test the file path to see if the string matches the glob?

```
let path = ['/home/location/file.scss','/home/location/file.cat'];
let pattern = '**/*.{sass,scss}';

path.forEach(file => {
    if(/* Test success */) {
        // read file and process it's content
    }
});
```

Comment: Use any glob or minimatcher from the bunch of available in npm or write yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use regex? Because you could convert the pattern to regex as `/\.s[ac]ss$/i`, and then do

```
path.forEach(file => {
  if (file.match(pattern)) {
  }
});
```

There's also [glob-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-to-regexp), in the case you have to write the pattern in glob.

Comment: I was able to use the link to get this to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) `npm install minimatch`

Then you can match against your test array with

```
var minimatch = require("minimatch");

let path = ['/home/location/file.scss','/home/location/file.cat'];
let pattern = '**/*.{sass,scss}';

path.forEach(file => {
    if(minimatch(file, pattern) {
        // read file and process it's content
    }
});
```

Although if you are just going to do something with the files I would use it differently, or use http://github.com/isaacs/node-glob